# Propel orm 1.6, symfony 1.4 embeded I18N form

Tags: internationalization, symfony1, symfony-1.4, propel, symfony-forms

I use propelorm (propel 1.6) plugin and symfony 1.4.20.

I have book table with I18n, and this book have relation with gallery table which also have I18n. I fill all book form fields, added two gallery images, filled all images fields. Click on save - it seems all ok: book fields are ok, first and second image have been uploaded, but only first image have filled i18n fields, second image all i18n fields are empty. What's the prob ?

(there's no redeclared doSave(), save(), bind() and other form methods)

## schema:

```
  book:
    id:                   ~
    title:                { type: varchar(255), required: true }
    author:               { type: varchar(255), required: true }
    description:          { type: longvarchar, required: true }
    sortable_rank:        { type: integer, required: true }
    is_active:            { type: boolean, default: 1 }
    _indexes:
      active_sort:        [ is_active, sortable_rank ]
    _propel_behaviors:
      sortable:
        rank_column:      sortable_rank
      i18n:
        i18n_columns:     [title, description, author]
        locale_column:    culture
        locale_alias:     culture
        default_locale:   en

  book_gallery:

    id:                 ~
    book_id: { type: integer, foreignTable: book, foreignReference: id, required: true, onDelete: cascade }
    title:              { type: varchar(255), required: true }
    image:              { type: varchar(255), required: true }
    _propel_behaviors:
      i18n:
        i18n_columns:    [title]
        locale_column:   culture
        locale_alias:    culture
        default_locale:  en
```

## book form:

```
$languages = LanguageQuery::create()->getAllAsArray(); // returns like array('en' => 'english', ...);
$this->embedI18n(array_keys($languages));
$this->widgetSchema->setLabels($languages);
$this->embedRelation('BookGallery', array(
  'title'               => 'Application book store list',
  'item_pattern'        => 'Application book store %index%',
));
```

## book gallery form:

```
$languages = LanguageQuery::create()->getAllAsArray(); // same as in book form
$this->embedI18n(array_keys($languages));
$this->widgetSchema->setLabels($languages);
```

Comment: By saying _second image_, you mean second book_gallery object has empty i18n field(s) (title field)?

Comment: Yes, I mean second 'book_gallery' object, i18n 'title' field.